# Elastic search how can I query either multi match or functions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three following parameters that I will pass to run the query, which are;

- **query** - *Either a place name, description or empty,*
- **lat** - *Either latitude of a place or empty,*
- **lon** - *Either longitude of a place or empty*

Based on above parameters, I get to query list of `items` based on `query` scores, then calculate the distance between `result` and `lat, lon`.

Now, I have the following script to get the `items` based on `query` and `distance`;

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "multi_match" : {
                            "query": "Lippo", 
                            "fields": [ "name^6", "city^5", "country^4", "position^3", "address_line^2", "description"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "gauss": {
                        "position": {
                            "origin":  "-6.184652, 106.7518749",
                            "offset": "2km",
                            "scale": "10km",
                            "decay": 0.33
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But the thing is, if `query` is empty, there will be no result at all. What I want is, the result is based on either `query` or `distance`.

Is there anyway to achieve this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting the [zero_terms_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-zero) option of multi-match to `all` should allow you to get the results when query is empty.

Example :

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "multi_match" : {
                            "query": "Lippo", 
                            "fields": [ "name^6", "city^5", "country^4", "position^3", "address_line^2", "description"],
                          "zero_terms_query" : "all"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "gauss": {
                        "position": {
                            "origin":  "-6.184652, 106.7518749",
                            "offset": "2km",
                            "scale": "10km",
                            "decay": 0.33
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has done it for me.. But, I finally removed my `functions` to check for distance. I ended up using simple `query` and `filter`. Thank you

Comment: Can you post ^^ this version also.